# Visual Studio crashing when trying to diff or compare files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, crash, diff

I'm using TFS for source control and the other day I undocked my laptop while running VS. I couldn't connect to the internet and then unfortunately there was an unexpected shutdown. Since then I have not been able to go into pending changes and compare the file to it's previous version. When I do, it crashes Visual Studio.

I can change the user tool in Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server to use a third party diff checker and it works no problem. However, I've gotten used to Visual Studio's diff checker and would like to continue using it, if only because it doesn't open a separate window to diff in.

Since I'm not sure as to the source of the problem, my question is two-fold:

First, how do I fix Visual Studio's diff checker and stop it from crashing every time I try to compare with previous version.

Or, if the issue lies with TFS, why is it crashing and how do I fix it?

Comment: Some files might have gotten corrupted. Have you tried repairing VS? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I only tried repairing TFS, not VS. I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Is it devenv.exe that crashes? Or another process? You could use ProcDump from SysInternals to get a dump file. Maybe the stacktrace will give you more information.

Comment: I downloaded ProcDump and launched VS using it to catch any exceptions. [This](http://pastebin.com/1fkMwFfZ) was the output, and I realized I didn't have the TFS2JIRA extension our team uses installed so I installed that then reran Visual Studio.

[This](http://pastebin.com/JrqrkhMY) was the output I got after running it with the plugin installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on Visual Studio Menu:

- **TOOLS** > **Options**

Then on Left Panel:

- **Text Editor** > **HTML** > **Advanced**

And finally on Right Panel:

- **Extension Management** > **Identify Helpful Extensions**

Change this setting to false.

This is an old question, but I needed to fix this recently, so the bug still exists!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to Tools -> Options -> Source control -> Plug-in Selection and changing the plug-in to "Git"

Comment: Although not a valid response, i still find this to be a very useful comment. It would solve a lot of my problems for sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to disable ability to Identify Helpful Extensions:
   Go to **Tools**->**Options**->**Text Editor**->**Html**->**Advanced**->**Extension Management**->**Identify Helpful Extensions** and switch to **false**.
2. You can start VS in safe mode with ["/SafeMode"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) param.